# Evaluate string ```$((expression))```-like and save in a variable

Tags: command-line, bash

This will sound pretty awkward for some of you. Suppose I have a string which represents some `$((expression))`, arithmetic expression mathematical like `'$((1+1))'`. I wish to perform it and deliver its result to a variable.

Example:

```bsh
$ expression='$((5+5))'
$ echo $expression 
'$((5+5))'

$ # Expected result: 10
```

How can I evaluate that string and store its result?

Comment: Oh, I may cook a great pasta with all that macarronic mistakes, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're evaluating a string try `eval`.

```
str="$[ 5 + 5 ]"
eval "numb=$str"    # Turns into `numb=$[ 5 + 5 ]`
echo $numb    # Outputs 10
```

`eval` can execute strings as if they were shell code. Be careful! If `$str` can contain special characters it may break your script or even create a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

Just store it in variable like you would normally do.

```
$ result=$((5+5))
$ echo $result 
10
```

If this is not what you meant, [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1391781/edit) your post and post additional information.

Comment: I updated the question for better undestannding of my case. But I appreciate the answers sofar! :-)

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto In your edit, you used almost the same code. This answer is exactly what you want in this case. The only error you have is that use the quotes on the `$((5+5))` part, you need to remove that.

Comment: Well, the operation I need to evaluate has quotes. Then, I am afraid I cannot evaluate them.

Answer (score 0):

If it is actually mathematical, specifically if it involves simple integer arithmetic, you can use exactly the format you have:

```
$ var=$((1+1))
$ echo "$var"
2
```

The same goes if it is a command. For example, slightly more complicated math can be done by piping to `bc`:

```bsh
## simple integer math works
$ echo $((3 * 2))
6
## fractions fail
$ echo $((1.3 * 2))
bash: 1.3 * 2: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".3 * 2")
## bc works
$ echo "1.3 * 2" | bc
2.6
```

So, to store that in a variable, you just use standard [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
$ var=$(echo "1.3 * 2" | bc)
$ echo "$var"
2.6
```

Finally, you also have the `eval` builtin (see `help eval` in `bash`):

```
$ help eval
eval: eval [arg ...]
    Execute arguments as a shell command.
    
    Combine ARGs into a single string, use the result as input to the shell,
    and execute the resulting commands.
    
    Exit Status:
    Returns exit status of command or success if command is null.
```